# How to add property in module in Rails CouchRest Model to support multiple inheritance?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-models, couchrest

In my class, I want to include multiple modules.  Each module can
define its own property to persist in couchDB.

Here is an example:

```
module Owner
 property :name
end

module Animal
 property :type
end

class Cat
 include Owner
 include Animal
end
```

This doesn't work.  I got this error: "undefined method `property'".
I tried added CouchRest::Model::Embeddable but it won't work for
module either.  All the examples I am seeing are extending from
CouchRest::Model::Base.  However, I won't be able to use this approach
because Ruby doesn't support multiple inheritance.

I won't be able to change the underlying JSON format. My desired format is {"name":"tom","type":"cat"}.

Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to http://www.couchrest.info/model/embedding.html I think your example would be:

```
class Owner < CouchRest::Model::Base
 include CouchRest::Model::Embeddable
 property :name
end

class Animal < CouchRest::Model::Base
 include CouchRest::Model::Embeddable
 property :type
end

class Cat
 property :owner, Owner
 property :animal, Animal
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea!  This doesn't seem to work for me.  I won't be able to change the underlying JSON format.  My desired format is {"name":"tom","type":"cat"}.  Your code would generate a format of {"owner":{"name":"tom"}, "animal":{"type":"cat"}}